# how to use vb update current date time?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2015

i was doing a update record but i cant update the time to my access file

the Issue_Daate data type are Date/Time and format i set is as general date

here is my code

```
Dim totalprice As Decimal = FormatCurrency(total_after_gst)
    Dim today As DateTime = System.DateTime.Now
    Dim status As String = "Completed"
    Dim sql1 As String = "Update [ordertbl] SET [Total_Price]=" & totalprice & ", [Issue_date]=" & today & ", [Status]='" & status & "' Where [ID] = " & code & " "
    Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql1, conn)

    cmd1.Connection = conn
        cmd1.ExecuteScalar()
```

i have an error which is

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '19/6/2016 03:27:52'.
```

i no sure which operator are missing=

Comment: You need to quote the date. But even better would be use to use parameters and prepared statements. Concatenating SQL is a sure way to end up with weird bugs like this and it's also a vector for attacks.

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL string do just a

```
[Issue_date]=getdate()
```

or

```
[Issue_date]=getutcdate()
```

Or, if you insist to do it in VB, then first do a `select getdate()` on the SQL server because maybe the date formats of VB and SQL are different. Then format your date in VB according to the SQL format and put it between single apostrophes.